# How to properly reference the appendix

Tags: citations, supporting-information

I have an appendix in addition to my thesis. How do I refer to this correctly?

Which version is the correct one?

1. As seen in the Appendix A1
2. As seen in Appendix A1

And how does it work if I refer to the appendix as a whole?

Comment: This is rather about English writing and I'm not a native speaker. I suspect both are OK (the upper case in the beginning of "Appendix A1" makes the whole thing a name, so it can do without "the", but I don't think "the" is wrong either). It should be "as seen in the appendix" without the A1. But there may be better expertise than mine.

Comment: Use 'as seen in the appendix' to refer to the appendix as a whole, or 'as seen in Appendix A1'. Capitalisation should only be used when refering to titles.

Comment: "Appendix A1" suggests that there exists at least Appendix A2 (and possibly A3 etc as well as B1, B2, etc) and so I would recommend _not_ writing "the Appendix A1" at all.  Indeed, if this is the only Appendix as you say,, why name it A1? Just call it _the_ Appendix and be done with it.